# Foreach loop shows only few items

Tags: php, database, codeigniter, foreach

I'm working with CodeIgniter.
I need to get some data from database with a foreach loop.
I have 4 items in the database, but the loop retrieve only two of them (the items with id 2 and 4).
This is the code in the for the foreach in the controller:

```
  $this->load->model('home_model');

        $data['query']=$this->home_model->get_films($limit);

        if ($data['query']) {
         $data['main_content'] = 'home';   
         $data['film'] = array();   
         foreach($data['query'] as $film_info) {
         $data['film'] = array(
          'id' => $film_info->id,   
          'poster_src' => $film_info->film_poster_src,   
          'title' => $film_info->film_name,
          'year' => $film_info->film_year,  
          'genre_id' => $film_info->genre_id,
         );

         $this->db->select('*');
         $this->db->from('genres');
         $this->db->where('id', $film_info->genre_id);
         $query1 = $this->db->get();
         $genre_info = $query1->row();
         $data['genre_name'] = $genre_info->genre_name;

         $this->db->select('*');
         $this->db->from('votes');
         $this->db->where('film_id', $film_info->id);
         $this->db->where('vote', '1');
         $query2 = $this->db->get();
         $data['votes_count'] = $query2->num_rows();
        }
        $this->load->view('template', $data);
```

This is the code in the model:

```
<?php

class Home_model extends CI_Model
{
    function get_films($limit)
    {
        $query = $this->db->get('films', $limit, $this->uri->segment(2));
        return $query->result();
    }
}
```

And this is the code in the view:

```
<div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4">
     <div class="thumbnail">
      <img src="<?php echo $film['poster_src'] ?>" alt="Film poster">
      <div class="caption">
        <h3><?php echo $film['title'] ?></h3>
        <p>Year: <?php echo $film['year'] ?></p> 
        <p>Genre: <?php echo $genre_name ?></p>
        <p>Votes: <?php echo $votes_count ?></p>
        <p><a href="#" class="btn btn-primary" role="button">Watch</a> <a href="#" class="btn btn-default" role="button">Add to bookmarks</a></p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

If I put the foreach code in the view, it works properly.

Comment: have you done a `var_dump / print_r` on `$data['query']` to see if it has 4 elements?

Comment: Yes, and it shows 4 items'arrays.

Comment: what is your problem then? in the view?

Comment: I'm not sure, because it seems to be right.

Comment: I don't understand why if I put the code in the view it works perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

I am not 100% sure so don't vote if false just make me aware i will try another way if possible.in foreach loop try to put the data in another array like this

```
$new_array[] = $the_result_value_you want
```

then you will be able to use $new_array outside the loop